# What does "folks got high at a quarter to five" in this song?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics

This line is in 'Great DJ' by 'The Ting Tings'.

> Fed up with your indigestion.
> Swallow words one by one.
> **Folks got high at a quarter to five.**
> Don’t you feel your growing up undone.

I can get those three lines above except the one I'm inquiring about.
Is there any specific meaning in 'a quarter to five'?
Like, if there's anything especially happens 'at a quarter to five'?

I cannot find any reference on google.

Comment: Probably this relates to an actual event where some people took drugs at that time of day. There's nothing special about it.

Comment: As @chasly-supportsMonica says, nothing special from an English language standpoint.  The general vibe of the first verse is one of malaise and boredom (nothing to do in the afternoon but get high) which then changes through the rest of the song.

Comment: 16:45 may be considered a little early to start using intoxicating substances (alcohol or marijuana). In Britain, certainly, many people consider it bad form to have a drink before early evening, when they may say "the sun is over the yard-arm". The naval expression originally meant "around 11 AM to 12 noon".

Comment: Thank you, everybody!!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Could this be made into an answer?  I'm going through some of the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 1):

From Michael Harvey's comment:

> 16:45 may be considered a little early to start using intoxicating substances (alcohol or marijuana). In Britain, certainly, many people consider it bad form to have a drink before early evening, when they may say "the sun is over the yard-arm". The naval expression originally meant "around 11 AM to 12 noon".

Part of the reason for this idea is probably that you need to stay sober until you've finished the day's work.  But the people in the song, it's implied, either don't have any work to do or don't care whether it gets done or not, so they go straight to getting high.

There's no significance to the particular time of 16:45, rather than any other point rather too early in the afternoon, that I know of; presumably it was just chosen because it fitted the rhythm well.